# how to check xpath expression (if valid/not) before scraping data with spider

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy, truthiness

Probably you have realized by title, I am using scrapy and xpath to extract data. I tried and provided xpaths from file to the spider (to make spider generic - not to edit often) As required, I am able to extract data in the format required.

Further, now I want to check the xpath expression (relative to webpage specified in spider) if the xpath provided is valid or not (incase if the html style has changed, then my xpath will be invalid). Regarding this I want to check my xpath expression before spider starts.

How do I test my xpath's correctness? or is there any way to do truth testing? Please help.

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "example"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = ["file:///<filepath>.html"]
def __init__(self):
    self.mt = ""
def parse(self, response):
    respDta = dict()
    it_lst = []
    dtData = response.selector.xpath(gx.spcPth[0])
    for ra in dtData:
        comoodityObj = ra.xpath(gx.spcPth[1])
        list = comoodityObj.extract()
        cmdNme = list[0].replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
        cmdNme = cmdNme.replace("Header text: ", '')
        self.populate_item(response, respDta, cmdNme, it_lst, list[0])
    respDta["mt"] = self.mt
    jsonString = json.dumps(respDta, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
    return jsonString
```

`gx.spcPth` gx.spcPth is from other function which provides me xpath. And it has been used in many instances in rest of the code. I need to check xpath expression before spider starts throughout the code, wherever implemented

Comment: Ultimate goal to achieve is to set the scrapy on crontab and forget about it. It should generate detailed error (error at so and so xpath) when my xpath is invalid for that webpage (means page changed). At this point I can change in the input file rather than editing the code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do, I just don't see why. The whole process of running a spider is in the same time your "testing" process - simple as this: if the result of xpath is empty and it should return something, than something is wrong. Why don't you just check the xpath results and use the scrapy logging to mark it as a warning, error or critical, whatever you want. Simple as this:

```
from scrapy import log

somedata = response.xpath(my_supper_dupper_xpath)
# we know that this should have captured
# something, so we check
if not somedata:
    log.msg("This should never happen, XPath's are all wrong, OMG!", level=log.CRITICAL)
else:
    # do your actual parsing of the captured data, 
    # that we now know exists
```

After that, just run your spider and relax. When you see critical messages in your output log, you'll know its time to shit bricks. Otherwise, everything is ok.

Comment: `Else:
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`
I am biologist not a great programmer

Comment: Ultimate goal to achieve is to set the scrapy on crontab and forget about it. It should generate detailed error (error at so and so xpath) when my xpath is invalid for that webpage (means page changed). At this point I can change in the input file rather than editing the code again.

Comment: The `IndentationError` means that you just copied my code without thinking. It is not a production code, its just an example to get you started. Notice that there is no code after the `else` statement, but there should be. Nevertheless, this sets you on the right path, but if you want more automated control, just output to a file instead, or send yourself an email or something, whatever is required to get your attention about the failing xpath expressions. And you can ofcourse include additional details about which is failing, my code was just a simple example, expand it.

Comment: In the above spider parse code,  `dtData = response.selector.xpath(gx.spcPth[0])` extracts data from the webpage with `gx.spcPth[0]` as the xpath which stores the extracted data in `dtData` variable. This variable is iterated further for extracting relevant data.

So, if I am not wrong, I did this.
`dtData = response.selector.xpath(gx.spcPth[0])

 if not dtData:

        for ra in dtData:

            print ("Whatever error")

        comoodityObj = ra.xpath(gx.spcPth[1])

        list = comoodityObj.extract()

        cmdNme = list[0].replace(u'\xa0', u' ')`

Comment: In the above spider parse code,  `dtData = response.selector.xpath(gx.spcPth[0])` extracts data from the webpage with `gx.spcPth[0]` as the xpath which stores the extracted data in `dtData` variable. This variable is iterated further for extracting relevant data.

I did the what ever you said using `dtData` if I am not wrong I don't need `else`!!, instead using `log.msg` I used `print` and code works, but if there is error it is not printed.

Any taught's on this..

Comment: You can't use `print`, use log. Scrapy uses Twisted which is highly asynchronous and there is no way to really know when your print will actually come on `stdout`, most likely it will get dumped all together at the end or something similar. Log module uses a queue, so that the lines go out in the correct order. So when you see your error log, you see it exactly when the page in question is being parsed. On the other hand, if you really *never ever* see the output of print, then the condition is never met so you should check your code. Paste it in your question as edit and I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to test out how Scrapy will use the xpath you provided to the spider is to just use the [Scrapy Shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html).

```
$ scrapy shell <url>
```

That will give you a `sel` object that you can run xpaths against:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//title/text()')
```

If you want some really quick tests, install the "XPath Helper" Chrome extension. It's my favorite extension for testing out and determining xpaths very quickly:

[XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en)

You simply visit a site in Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+X, and type in an xpath. You'll see results on the right-hand side.

Comment: I would like to schedule that like scrapy - meaning I want the check to happen programmatically. Show me errors, when there are errors

Comment: I've read your other question and your comments, and it seems like you want some way to automatically check all your xpaths for your expected values, and report any inconsistencies. This just isn't realistic.

I have done almost exactly the same thing in my own projects, but you'll have to write it yourself from scratch, and it will vary greatly depending on the data you're expecting. I'm not sure someone here is going to be able to help you with what you're looking for.

Comment: I see what you mean, one correction about _my expected values_. There is no such thing as expected values, I just want to check if the object is created when my xpath is used at instances, without getting this `IndentationError: `.

In the above spider parse code, `dtData = response.selector.xpath(gx.spcPth[0])` extracts data from the webpage with `gx.spcPth[0]` as the `xpath` which stores the extracted data in `dtData` object variable

Comment: `IndentationError` is an error with indenting your code, it is a syntax error and has nothing to do with logic of implementation or scrapy.

Comment: @pyDev_ram: Whatever editor you're using to write your code, make sure you aren't using tabs for indentation (convert all tabs to spaces). According to PEP8, which you should be following as a Python dev, you should always be using spaces, not tabs. Based on your code above, I'd guess that's what would be causing an `Indentation Error`.

Answer (score 0):

The Scrapy shell is an interactive shell where you can try and debug your scraping code very quickly.

Ref: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

The shell is used for testing XPath or CSS expressions and see how they work and what data they extract from the web pages you’re trying to scrape

Answer (score 0):

the shell is the way to go.
if needed you can even invoke it within your spider as described in the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html?highlight=invoke%20shell#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses)
I found this useful sometimes.

Comment: This looks like an option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do xpath validation with [Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html):

```py
from scrapy.selector import Selector

try:
    my_xpath = '//div/some/xpath'
    Selector(text="").xpath(my_xpath)
    print("valid xpath")
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also should not only make sure that you have a 200 code response, but also you should check what is the actual response:

```
view(response)
```

Then, As JoneLinux said you need to use

```
scrapy shell 'URL'
```

but instead of `sel.xpath()`

you should use:

```
response.xpath('//YourXpath...')
```